# ansi c - auto clean up ugly code

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm dealing with some code written in manner that is really, honestly, ugly. Is there a way to auto enforce proper tabs and remove all of the random multi-line white space entries?

Comment: I don't think it's even possible to have clean code in ANSI C... I'd say C99 is the minimum since you at least get `//` comments and interleaved code/declarations.

Comment: [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) is a very customizable code beautifier. I'd advice using it with [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Are you dealing with a proper IDE? All the major ones have some functionality for this. A quick google search will lead you to free/paid programs that have extended functionality

Comment: Just [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old Unix people have a solution for everything, including lazy programmers. Enter [GNU indent.](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/)

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any editor but I would prefer using Vim, with vim you can actually give proper tabs by selecting all the code in visual mode and then '='. 
You will also have to set sw=3 for only 3 space equal tab - preferred spacing in most of the code. Also set expandtabs this will ensure the code will look the same as it will replace '\t' with 3 space

Comment: In emacs you can do the same thing by selecting all the code and doing a ctrl+alt+\

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is easy in any decent editor. And so there is no need for a holy war between the [3-space indent](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/c-coding-conventions) camp and the 4-space indent camp ( [a](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) [b](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) ).